# Swift Calendar integration

Tags: ios, calendar, swift3, touch-event

I'm just starting out with swift and so I'm trying to make an app that can keep track of my dad's employee payroll schedule and employee attendance.  So I figured a good start would be to have a calendar type view in which a touch event would bring up a pop up menu so he can check which employees were present. On payday it would add up the days by keeping a counter and then multiplying it by a entered pay rate.

I figured this could be done by manipulating the already familiar apple calendar and editing the functionality a bit but it would be simpler. So my questions are...

- Is it possible to import the apple calendar into my app (so I don't have to worry about the accuracy of my calendar/having to make one)?
- Would it then be possible to edit the functionality of it? i.e. make the add event function into the simple employee attendance menu I need.

If anyone could help or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated. There's just a lot of info out there and some of it is outdate because of swift 3 so it can be a bit confusing. I'm a noob but not new to coding so I'm very determined to learn and read!

Comment: Dont think there's buildin calendar view, so you have to use some other lib, checkout awesome iOS in github to find suitable one for you

Comment: Click on this [CocoaPod Link](https://cocoapods.org/?q=calenda) which shows you the top Calendar libraries out there. This will make your life a lot easier. Apple does not have a build in calendar view.

Comment: @Tj3n Sweet! Thanks!

Comment: @JTAppleCalendarforiOSSwift this is perfect, thanks!

Comment: You can also try  'FSCalendar' pod.